# java.lang.ClassFormatError: LVTT entry for 'list' in class file

Tags: netbeans-7, weblogic-10.x

I have one Web application:
IDE Netbeas 7.2
Weblogic server 11 g

this WApp compile and run on Tomcat 7.0.22

and on Weblogic compile too but don't run. Error:

**java.lang.ClassFormatError: LVTT entry for 'list' in class file [file.class]**

any idea??

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try compiling with `-g:none`. Maybe this helps over the error in the variable table.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#options) for the javac options.

Comment: It works! I did just set Generate Debugging Info param in false: NetBeans> Project Properties> Build> Compiling > Generate Debugging Info     1 point to cpt.jazz =)